# Azure ADB2C : Disable e-mail verification, conditionally

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure B2C for authentication of our online application.
We now have a very specific case, where a customer is willing to sign in with un-existing e-mail addresses.  (so basically using them as user name / pwd).

While this is something we hoped to avoid, it seems we have to allow this.

I know it's possible to disable e-mail address verification, but then it will be the case for every user, and that's something we don't want.

We are currently already using an Azure B2C connector and we could look up if the e-mail address is allowed to sign up, without e-mail verification.  So ideally we would love to make this conditional (e-mail verification is not needed in case an e-mail address has been marked as pre-approved).  Is this behavior even possible, or not?

Is there an option to have two different user flows, maybe?
(we want to limit functionality for users that have not verified their e-mail address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and straightforward. You can first collect email address only from the user using a [self-asserted technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile). Then you call your [REST API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to check if this user should go through verification or not. Here is sample code to collect email only and then make a conditional decision:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/dynamic-sign-up-sign-in

Your first orchestration step would be:

```
   <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckIfVerificationNeeded-Exchange"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CheckIfVerificationNeeded" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

You should set up a [claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema) called `IsVerificationRequired`. The value should get set by your API response as an `OutputClaim`.

You need the self-asserted technical profile to collect the email. That technical profile should call your REST API technical profile as a [validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile).

Later on in your user journey, you only display verification if `IsVerificationRequired = true`.

It would look something like this:

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="X" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
           <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>IsVerificationRequired</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="EmailVerification-Exchange"
              TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

You can make this cleaner and more sophisticated using [SubJourneys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/subjourneys), which I highly recommend. However, I have kept this simple to convey the concept.

I would greatly appreciate if you can select this answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great explanation.  While I didn't take the time to switch to custom policies (see answer below), it surely deserves to be marked as correct answer.  Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of Ali definitely is the most structural and robust approach to the problem, I want to point out a work around that seems to work good for me as well.

I have created a second policy (same claims , same API connector deployment, same secrets , etc).  There, I am just marking the email address not to require verification, in the Page Layout.

However, I have created two API connector types.  Pointing to the same API deployment, but with passing a query parameter (`&emailVerified=true` or `&emailVerified=false`) to the connector.
In the connector logic, I do the specific validation and persist the flag with my user profile, so I can know in the future if a profile has been verified or not.

Once the user is signed up, I can easily leverage the same login policy as before, just knowing that in the Claims, there is a different `tfp` claim that could also be used for verification.